# Como puedo evitar la modificación del código HTML desde el cliente al inspeccionar pagina

Tags: ajax, post, input, id

El problema que tengo es que al enviar un ID al servidor por método POST de Ajax para posteriormente modificar el respectivo elemento de la base de datos MYSQL, el usuario puede modificar valor de ese ID porque esta almacenado en un input con el atributo hidden y este puede abrir el inspector de la pagina y borrar el atributo hidden y cambial el valor del ID, de ese modo AJAX envía un valor equivoco y MYSQL modifica el elemento incorrecto; ¿existe alguna técnica o método para evitar la modificación del HTML? .

Comment: No puedes. Guarda el valor en la sesión en tu servidor, o valida de nuevo que el usuario tiene permisos para modificar ese elemento antes de modificarlo.

Comment: Tal como dice @SJuan76, no puedes, eso es algo que pasa al control del navegador. Te recomiendo darle un vistazo a [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Además, es **MUY** recomendable la implementación de [JWT](https://jwt.io/)